# Regular expression working fine until rounds brackets come to play

Tags: .net, regex

in production I got a nasty problem that I figured out related to a regular expression taking forever:

The regex:

```
(?'Response'{\s*("([\w]+)"\s*:\s*"?((?'Message'[\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:;_']+(,[,\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:_]+)?)+)"\s*,*\s*)+})
```

The regex itself works fine with a message like the following:

```
{ "ABC":[ { "Type":"K", "Message":"Any type of reasonable message 12345" } ]
```

Everything crash if I do something like that (adding round brackets for example):

```
{ "ABC":[ { "Type":"K", "Message":"Any type of reasonable message 12345 (reasonable)" } ]
```

I tried a lot of avenues but I could find a way to "include" ( and ) as legitimate characters.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What language or regex library are you using?

Comment: `([\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:;_']+(,[,\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:_]+)?)+` will lead to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html): when the optional does not match, you have `(…+)+`

Comment: @melpomene standard System.Text.RegularExpression in .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-3.5

Comment: Why are you not just using a JSON parser? That would massively simplify things.

Comment: @melpomene because the inner part ( { "Type":"K", "Message":"Any type of reasonable message 12345 (reasonable)" } ) can be in differnt type of Json structure and I didn't find a reasonable way to parse it properly (parsing it as a Json was my first approach)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, if we don't have other options to exercise, maybe we would simplify our expression to something similar to:

```
({\s*"([\w]+)"\s*:\s*"[A-Z]+"\s*,(\s*"[\w]+"\s*:\s*"[\w\d\s)(:;.']+"\s*,?)+\s*})
```

even though I'm not sure what might be probable inputs and desired outputs.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bSZFNm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As a comment has pointed out, the very best thing to do here is to use a tool that parses JSON. This will allow you to have more control over the data as it changes over time. If there is a problem parsing it as JSON, then that may be the better place to focus effort.

I would like to point out that you don't seem to be matching the literal `[]`, and so it would seem that your match could potentially match a similar values inside of the first section, where you currently have `"ABC"`, so do be careful about sanitizing the data.

There are two ways of going about adding in parentheses. You could either continue doing what you are currently doing, trying to think of everything that you might want to allow in that string, and so you would simply add in the additional characters as you come across them. As such, this solution would work:

```
(?'Response'{\s*("([\w]+)"\s*:\s*"?((?'Message'[\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:;_'\(\)]+(,[,\s\w\d\.\\\-\/:_]+)?)+)"\s*,*\s*)+})
```

Demonstrated at https://regex101.com/r/xqP8BF/1

However, you may find it easier to simply exclude anything that you don't want to match, specifically, the `"`:

```
(?'Response'{\s*("([\w]+)"\s*:\s*"?("(?'Message'[^"]*)")\s*,*\s*)+})
```

Demonstrated here: https://regex101.com/r/pyaMaD/1

This later example is much more simple. Of course, when you're done, sanitize the data. Also, depending on the data you receive, you may need to account for escaped `"`, but I believe that you would need to do that even with the othe regex.